# Python: how to act on re's matched string

Tags: python, regex, coercion

The following

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'\1' * 2, 'test line 123')
```

gives

```
'test line 123123'
```

is there a way to make it give

```
'test line 246'
```

?

`float()` coercion doesn't work:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', float(r'\1') * 2, 'test line 123')
could not convert string to float: \1
```

nor do `eval` or `exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) can also be a callable, which lets you do:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda match:'%d' % (int(match.group(1))*2), 'test line 123')
```

BTW, there really is no reason to use float over int, as your regex does not include periods and will always be a non-negative integer

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to supply a function as the `repl` argument to [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
In [7]: re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m:'%.0f'%(float(m.group(1))*2), 'test line 123') 
Out[7]: 'test line 246'
```

Each match is converted to `float`, doubled, and then converted to string using the appropriate format.

This can be simplified a little bit if the number is integer, but your question specifically mentions `float`, so that's what I've used.